# SQL join two tables without keys/relations

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, one of them has weeks of year, and the second table has categories. I need to create a table that contains each week and each category, but there's no fields/keys that intersect in two tables:

Table 1:

```
week1
week2
week3
week4
```

Table 2:

```
Cat1
Cat2
```

Resulting table:

```
week1 cat1
week1 cat2
week2 cat1
week2 cat2
...
week4 cat1
week4 cat2
```

I'd like to do this without using many cursors/looping.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

This will get you every combination of all columns from Table1 and Table2.

Comment: duh! of course. sometimes i think of more complicated ways around simple problems. thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried just

```
 SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```