# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd and multiple select statements within the input

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

The problem I am facing lies with the use of the invoke-sqlcmd command below

```
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $sqlfile -ServerInstance $DB
```

The example sql within $sqlfile is:

```
SELECT TOP 2 FROM [TABLE1]
SELECT TOP 3 FROM [TABLE2]
```

The kind of output I am after would be a single result with both tables one after the other.

For example..

```
TABLE1
data1
data2
TABLE2
data1
data2
data3
```

Is this even possible?

I have attempted the same using **Invoke-Sqlcmd2** thinking that a PSCustomObject data type would be easier to play with..

```
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -InputFile $sqlfile-ServerInstance $DB -As PSObject
```

However this seems to only process the first select query and ignore the second.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a CROSS JOIN in the SQL File ?
Consider the following from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797785/sql-join-two-tables-without-keys-relations)

You would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```

And this will give you all data associated between both tables *regardless* if there is a relationship or not. If you want to JOIN via relationship, check some of the other SQL Joins, such as LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, etc

Comment: If you want to add specific columns, you would just replace the * with the column names, such as  col1, col2  .. etc

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific with the SQL.
A real life example of how this would work would not really work with any joins. 

For example, 

`select transtime, amount, accountid from #mytable1`
`select count(accountid),sum(amount) from #mytable1`

The sum data wouldn't really work being joined unfortunately.
In this instance, the purpose of the two outputs would be to
1.) Display some data from the temporary table #mytable1
2.) Display the count of the accountid column and summary of the amount column. 

You are correct though, that solution would work in other cases

Comment: Ahh alright, in this case it might be worthwhile to look into Stored Procedures if they will suit your case, as far as hooking these up with Powershell I am not too familiar with, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values/43767) might help for some of the SQL